# ROC curve for knn model

Tags: r, roc

I am using [ROCR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html) package and I was wondering how can one plot a ROC curve for `knn` model in R? Is there any way to plot it all with this package?

I don't know how to use the prediction function of `ROCR` for `knn`. Here's my example, i am using isolet dataset from UCI repository where i renamed the class attribute as y:

```
cl <- factor(isolet_training$y)
knn_isolet <- knn(isolet_training, isolet_testing, cl, k=2, prob=TRUE)
```

Now my question is, what are the arguments to pass to the prediction function of ROC. I tried the 2 below alternatives which are not working:

```
library(ROCR)
pred_knn <- prediction(knn_isolet$y, cl)
    pred_knn <- prediction(knn_isolet$y, isolet_testing$y)
```

Comment: ROCR is not bound to a specific model. The only information you need are the true labels and the predictions of a model. Can you please provide some code and tell us where exactly you get stuck ?

Comment: @steffen i added an example

Comment: you have opened a very similar question for solving the same problem. I suggest to edit this one and flag the other one for close (either you choose or the mods will ;)). I see no value to keep both open. If you do not agree, please comment.

Answer (score 3):

ROCR plots ROCs for binary classification only, and ISOLET has 26 classes.

Comment: You are right, I just realized it now myself, so I thought to use pROC, but there's another issue: I have to plot ROC curves of 6 different algorithms in one single plot and pROC supports only 2 curves in one plot. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: @blerta re: plotting multiple ROC curves with pROC; try adding add = TRUE to your plot.roc() command, to all but the first ROC you try to plot.